# Loading Images With Fresco From The Internal Storage

Tags: android, fresco

I am trying to do:

```
fun getBitmap(uri: String?) {
    val imagePipeline = Fresco.getImagePipeline()
    val builder = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(Uri.fromFile(File(uri)))
    val request = builder.build()
    val dataSource = imagePipeline.fetchDecodedImage(request, this)
    try {
        dataSource.subscribe(object : BaseBitmapDataSubscriber() {
            override fun onFailureImpl(dataSource: DataSource<CloseableReference<CloseableImage>>?) {
                Log.d("loadBackground", "fail")
            }

            override fun onNewResultImpl(bitmap: Bitmap?) {
                activity_levels.background = BitmapDrawable(resources, bitmap)
            }

            }, DefaultExecutorSupplier(1).forBackgroundTasks())
        } finally {
            dataSource?.close()
        }
    }
```

This is uri:

```
uri = "${directory.absolutePath}/background.jpg"
```

I always get into a method `onFailureImpl` with error *java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported uri scheme! Uri is...*

How to upload image from internal storage?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use

```
ImageRequest request = ImageRequest.fromFile(yourFile)
```

to get your image request

However, if you're using the Bitmap directly (like you do), you need to hold on to the `CloseableReference` and manage the lifecycle for the data, see http://frescolib.org/docs/writing-custom-views.html